# Get LatLng of place_changed event

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I'm using an autocomplete field to search addresses, and I want to retrieve the coordinates associated to this address when a `place_changed` event is triggered, but apparently I can't retrieve the `LatLng` object of the event:

```js
function initMap() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: {lat: 0,lng: 0},
    zoom: 5
  });

  let input = document.getElementById('input');
  let autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input,{types: ['geocode']});
  google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function(event) {
    map.panTo(event.latLng);
  });
}
```

```html
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MY_KEY&callback=initMap&libraries=places"></script>

<div id="map" style="height: 100%;">Map here</div>

<label for="input">Search address:</label>
<input type="text" id="input">
```

> TypeError: event is undefined

I know that this field is primarily for autocomplete, but does it also allow geocoding? If it doesn't, what is the best way to retrieve the `LatLng` object associated to the address that has been written?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need the event, you must use the `place.geometry.location` object of the place you have retrieved. Your listener would look like that:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function() {
    let place = this.getPlace();
    let pos = place.geometry.location;
    map.panTo(pos);
});
```

Comment: I'm OP, I answered my own question because I found the solution during the 90 minutes I can't post another question.

Comment: `asked 3 mins ago`, `answered 3 mins ago` :)